# Presentation of a group from a paper of Charles Ford

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-presentation

The question is very small - I am trying to understand an example of a group, but its presentation looks incomplete.

In a [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/some-results-on-the-schur-index-of-a-representation-of-a-finite-group/6E7DE0DE78D255B891518BBB18335C63), Charles Ford (1970) mentions following example of a group.

> Let $G$ be a group with following relations:
> $$
> A_1^7=1, \,\,\,\, A_2^{13}=1, \,\,\,\, A_1A_2=A_2A_1,\\
> X_1^3=Z, \,\,\,\, X_2^3=Z, \,\,\,\, Z^9=1, \,\,\,\, Z \mbox{ is central in } G\\
> X_1^{-1}A_1X_1=A_1^2, \,\,\,\, 
> X_2^{-1}A_2X_2=A_2^3 , \\
> A_1X_2=X_2A_1, \,\,\,\, A_2X_1=X_1A_2.
> $$

My question is very simple: are there no relation between $X_1$ and $X_2$?

I think, it should be mentioned, whether they commute or not. For example, if we mention $[X_1,X_2]=Z$, then we get one group, and if we had mentioned $[X_1,X_2]=1$, then the group will be different (non-isomorphic) from previous.

If anyone has came across this paper or work of Ford, can one tell what relation between $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be taken?

The author tries to give example of a (finite) group with some non-trivial Schur index of a representation.

Comment: There is a relation between $X_1$ and $X_2$: $X_1^3=X_2^3=Z$ and $Z\in Z(G)$. 
So $[X_1^3,X_2]=[X_2^3,X_1]=e$.

Comment: what is $[X_1,X_2]$? I think it can not be **deduced/computed** from other relations, as you did at end.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in the formula $A_1X_2=X_1A_1$. I think it should be $A_1X_2=X_2A_1$.

Comment: @kabenyuk: Thanks for noticing it; I repaired it.